# What are the MySql, FlatFile Database Differences?

Tags: php

I mean whats the difference between mysql and flat file database is it really slower to have "ff db"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flat file database has far less functionality than a relational database.  To name a couple of things, you lose explicit typing and indexing on columns, since the information in the file consists only of the rows of the table (and since you asked about speed, remember that indexing is what allows us to make fast queries).

Answer (score 0):

Basic differences:

A relational db removes redundancy in the data, flat file you are stuck with redundant data.

A relational db moves towards solving inconsistent update problems, flat file you need to do this yourself

A relational db has a lot of work done to increase speed, provide optimal searching and storage systems, type your data, etc. A flatfile system has none of this.

You may find more interest in the features of more advanced RDBMSes too, as MySQL is actually a pretty basic relational db. The extra features of PostgreSQL for example, with it's much improved concurrent access controls, etc.